# Replace the ascii apostrophe with a real apostrophe in a sql database

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am converting my classic asp to .Net using parameterized queries. My     problem is that in my classic apps I would replace the apostrophe with the ascii equivelent `&#39;`

Now I would like to replace that value in the database with a real apostrophe.  I am not sure how the syntax should be to do this.  I can find the `&#39;` but I am not sure how to replace.  The following is the simple update I am trying to run that errors out.

update tblCustomer set 
Name = replace(Name, `'&#39;'`, ''')

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Double up the apostrophe to escape it in a string literal

```
update tblCustomer set Name = replace(Name, '&#39;', '''')
```

Or use the `char` function

```
update tblCustomer set Name = replace(Name, '&#39;', CHAR(39))
```