# Select VarChar with apostrophes

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-injection, varchar

I have a SQL Server database that contains a `VarChar(50)` column. I am using ASP.NET/C# for this application.

I have protected my program from SQL injection so when I insert any text with an apostrophe in it, it will insert properly. I have confirmed this in the database.

However, now when I query the database for this `varchar` column, instead of getting apostrophes in the column, I am getting the unicode version of it (&#39 ;).

I use a `SqlDataSource` and bind it to a DataGridView. What could cause this conversion? How can I avoid it?

EDIT:
Seems that this problem is only occurs in textboxes, labels seem to be displaying them properly.

Thanks for your help.  This community here is awesome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fix data in the database: [Replace the ascii apostrophe with a real apostrophe in a sql database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4314601/replace-the-ascii-apostrophe-with-a-real-apostrophe-in-a-sql-database)

And how to correctly insert: 
[How to insert a value that contains an apostrophe (single quote)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1912095/how-to-do-a-sql-insert-with-a-value-with-an-apostrophe-in-it)

**-- Edit --**

This thread seems to shed more light on this issue: http://forums.asp.net/p/1554455/3818604.aspx

You could also try the `HtmlDecode(string)` method via http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility.htmldecode.aspx

Comment: You have misunderstood the problem.  Everything in the database is perfectly fine.  Apostraphes are apostraphes.  It is when I SELECT this data and attempt to use it in the problem that it converts to the unicode for no apparent reason?

Comment: Thanks for the edit.  I will test these on my code tomorrow to see if they fix the issue.

Comment: Server.HtmlDecode(string) seems to be the easiest/most reasonable solution.  Nice find!