# How to get apostrophe from database?

Tags: sql, sql-server, asp.net-mvc-3

> InformationTable

```
Father's name   
Mother's name
Id
Email
```

When i am retrieving these value from my sql server database table **InformationTable** in my asp.net mvc 3 application i found these item like     **Father&#39 ;s Name**

How do i do it?
Thanks in advance

Comment: `SELECT REPLACE(Column_Name, '&#39 ;', '''') ...`

Comment: may be you should put '' apostrophe

Comment: Try using replace `replace(Name, '&#39;', CHAR(39))`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Replace the ascii apostrophe with a real apostrophe in a sql database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4314601/replace-the-ascii-apostrophe-with-a-real-apostrophe-in-a-sql-database)

Comment: There are many data with apostrophe and without apostrophe. how do i distinguish them. @lad2025

Comment: @Coder of Code ,
 
There are many data with apostrophe and without apostrophe. how do i distinguish them

Comment: Its not duplicate @Coder of Code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use it for mvc in asp

```
@Html.Raw(HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(**Value**))
```